# C++ code summary tool

Tags: c++, source-code, code-analysis

I'm looking for a tool which will take as input a C++ source file, and output (in plain text, HTML, PNG, PDF, whatever format) a summary containing at least a list of the functions defined in the source file, and ideally some further information about defined types and variables, and what refers to what. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: "a C++ source file" - a single one? Or a whole project?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Preferably a single one, though if a project-based tool is available, and is all that's available, I'm willing to take a look at it.

Comment: A C++ file typically only contains one type, which is the class it defines (There are exceptions of course). Also, the header file which belongs to the CPP file often contains the type it defines and the methods. Therefore, I can't imagine how such a tool would be more useful than looking at the header file.

Comment: A single CPP file will typically include its header and probably other stuff. Should those be considered (we say "compilation unit") or not?